# Bash replace string at multiple places in a file from command line

Tags: text-processing, sed, string, replace

I have a file with the below content. I want to replace `chrome` with `chromeBackup` but not in all places.

```
Name=chrome
XXXXXXXXXXX
Run=bin -app "chrome/chrome.sh"
XXXXXXXXXXX
Vol.apps/chrome=chrome
XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Required output:

```
Name=chrome
XXXXXXXXXXX
Run=bin -app "chromeBackup/chromeBackup.sh"
XXXXXXXXXXX
Vol.apps/chromeBackup=chromeBackup
XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Can you describe the places that should and should not be replaced?

Comment: Check my "required output"

Comment: A good answer would operate on any input; otherwise, someone could just statically print your desired output.

Comment: In other words, one possible answer right now would be two tell you to open an editor and make the changes manually.

Comment: Your required output doesn't really clarify your desired behavior. Do you want the change only on lines that start with `Run=` or `Vol.apps`? Every line except ones that start with `Name=`? Only lines that contain a "p"? Something else?

Comment: @Nani Isn't my answer solving your problem? If so, then please tell the problem you are facing but editing your question.

Answer (score 7):

According to the information you have provided, you want to replace it at two places, so you can use:

```
sed -e /^Run/s/chrome/chromeBackup/g -e /^Vol/s/chrome/chromeBackup/g file_name
```

**Edit**

As @Kusalananda mentioned in his comment, shorter version is:

```
sed -E '/^(Run|Vol)/s/chrome/&Backup/g' file_name
```

Comment: Or possibly `sed -E '/^(Run|Vol)/s/chrome/&Backup/g'`.

Answer (score 1):

More general perhaps, change all instances except those on the line starting `Name=`

```
from="chrome"; to="${from}Backup"; sed "/^Name/! s/$from/$to/g" fileToChange
```

or just skip the first line

```
from="chrome"; to="${from}Backup"; sed "2,$ s/$from/$to/g" fileToChange
```

or only in the lines starting `Run` or `Vol`

```
from="chrome"; to="${from}Backup"; sed -E "/^Run|^Vol/ s/$from/$to/g" fileToChange
```